# Can't clone public repo from within Dockerfile

Tags: github, docker

I have the following line in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/assafg/youtube-remote.git ./youtube-remote
```

When executing sudo docker build -t 'yremote' .
I get the following error:

> Cloning into './youtube-remote'... fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/assafg/youtube-remote.git/': Could not resolve
>   host: github.com The command '/bin/sh -c git clone
>   https://github.com/assafg/youtube-remote.git ./youtube-remote'
>   returned a non-zero code: 128

Running clone command from command line works fine.

Comment: Looks like your container can't connect to the internet. Possibly because it was started with a weird networking option? Run this command to check default internet connectivity: `docker run ubuntu apt install -y git && git clone https://github.com/assafg/youtube-remote.git ./youtube-remote`

Comment: Thanks! I guess it was something with the network... I run you command and it worked, the I rerun mine, and it worked too.

Comment: @code_monk why don't you post this as an answer. It could prove useful to others as well.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if your container can't connect to the internet. Possibly because it was started with a weird networking option? Run this command to check default internet connectivity:

```
docker run ubuntu apt install -y git && \
git clone https://github.com/assafg/youtube-remote.git ./youtube-remote
```

If that container successfully pulls down the repo, it probably means the first container has a networking problem. Try to restart, or change networking settings.

[Docker Network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/) just became a first class citizen in the Docker ecosystem. It's a really fast-moving project. This advice applies to v1.8

Comment: `sudo service docker restart` worked for me! It really was a weird networking problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very scientific answer but sometimes docker restart helps especially in cases connected with docker network.